# .htaccess redirect with path variables

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

So I know I can use

```
RewriteRule ^/?old-path/(.*)$ /new-path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To redirect /old-path/{{page-name}} to /new-path/{{page-name}}

I need to redirect /old-path/{{something}}/{{page-name}} to /{{page-name}}

I'm assuming it's something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?old-path/(.*)$/(.*)$ /$2 [L,R=301]
```

But I'm worried that this might encapsulate something I'm not foreseeing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?old-path/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The regex works like this

```
^/?old-path/[^/]+/(.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: You're right, and thank you, but you were slightly after Sabuj Hassan

EDIT: You edited for a better answer.

Comment: @coulbourne OTOH, I was 13 seconds quicker ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to capture two groups from here. Just pick the second group as first.

```
RewriteRule ^/?old-path/[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you, you were correct, but hjpotter92 explained the logic